# Authentication failing on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

On my development machine I can login fine, but once on production, 
authentication fails for the base user created in the migration.

I can reset my password and upon doing so I am auto logged in, but 
when I logout and try to login again using the newly entered password, 
once again it tells my I have a bad email and/or password.

Any ideas to why this would be?

=== Update

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # default devise modules
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  ... 
end
```

Comment: have you tried to reset the password on localhost? do you even have it enabled; changeable or whatever module it uses?

Comment: I can change the password with no problems on my dev machine.  This is the first time I have used devise, but seeing as all works on my dev box all of the default settings seem to allow for this.  I have added a list of modules that are being used above.

Comment: Are you using the bundled devise authentication controllers/views?  Also, are you certain that you are using the same version of devise in development and production?

Comment: I am using v1.1.2 for both dev and prod.  As for the views/controllers, I haven't touched anything in the controllers and have only made aesthetic tweaks to the views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem on my staging server. The strangest is that it works in production env on my personal computer ...

Solved here : http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise/browse_thread/thread/20a73a2b7976806f

Thanks !